# Can I hide/show asp:Menu items based on role?

Tags: asp.net, roles

Am I able to hide certain menu items in an `asp:Menu` control based on role?

```
<asp:Menu ID="mTopMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="File">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="New Project" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Release Template" NavigateUrl="~/Release/ReleaseTemplate.aspx" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Release Schedule" NavigateUrl="~/Release/ReleaseSchedule.aspx" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Roles" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/AdminRoles.aspx" />
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

How can I make one of these items visible to only users in the Admin role?
I am using asp.net role provider.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can **bind the menu items to a site map and use the roles attribute**.  You will need to enable Security Trimming in your Web.Config to do this.  This is the simplest way.

Site Navigation Overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e468hxky.aspx

Security Trimming Info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx

SiteMap Binding Info:
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp

Good Tutorial/Overview here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx

Another option that works, but is less ideal is to use the **loginview** control which can display controls based on role.  This might be the quickest (but least flexible/performant) option.  You can find a guide here: http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2010/07/28/role-based-authorization-using-loginview-control.aspx

Answer (score 28):

You can remove unwanted menu items in Page_Load, like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
        {
            MenuItemCollection menuItems = mTopMenu.Items;
            MenuItem adminItem = new MenuItem();
            foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menuItems)
            {
                if (menuItem.Text == "Roles")
                    adminItem = menuItem;
            }
            menuItems.Remove(adminItem);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure there's a neater way to find the right item to remove, but this one works. You could also add all the wanted menu items in a Page_Load method, instead of adding them in the markup.

Answer (score 14):

I prefer to use the FindItem method and use the value path for locating the item.  Make sure your PathSeparator property on the menu matches what you're using in FindItem parameter.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // remove manage user accounts menu item for non-admin users.
        if (!Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            MenuItem item = NavigationMenu.FindItem("Users/Manage Accounts");
            item.Parent.ChildItems.Remove(item);  
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should probably do the above in the Menu's DataBound event rather than in Page_Load, since the DataBound event will run every time the data's bound to the menu, which could happen after Page_Load).

Answer (score 9):

This is best done in the MenuItemDataBound.

```
protected void NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        if (e.Item.NavigateUrl.Equals("/admin"))
        {
            if (e.Item.Parent != null)
            {
                MenuItem menu = e.Item.Parent;

                menu.ChildItems.Remove(e.Item);
            }
            else
            {
                Menu menu = (Menu)sender;

                menu.Items.Remove(e.Item);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Because the example used the NavigateUrl it is not language specific and works on sites with localized site maps.

Answer (score 3):

SIMPLE method may not be the best for all cases

```
        <%                
            if (Session["Utype"].ToString() == "1")
            {
        %>
        <li><a href="../forms/student.aspx"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span>STUDENT DETAILS</span></a></li>   
        <li><a href="../forms/UserManage.aspx"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i><span>USER MANAGEMENT</span></a></li>
        <%
              }
            else
             {
        %>                      
        <li><a href="../forms/Package.aspx"><i class="fa fa-object-group"></i><span>PACKAGE</span></a></li>
        <%
             }                
        %>
```

Comment: put this on html side of aspx page

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
protected void Menu1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   recursiveMenuVisit(Menu1.Items);
}

private void recursiveMenuVisit(MenuItemCollection items)
        {
            MenuItem[] itemsToRemove = new MenuItem[items.Count];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (MenuItem item in items)
            {
                if (item.NavigateUrl.Contains("Contact.aspx"))
                {
                    itemsToRemove[i] = item;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.ChildItems.Count > 0) recursiveMenuVisit(item.ChildItems);
                }
            }

            for(int j=0; j < i; j++)
            {
                items.Remove(itemsToRemove[j]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove a `MenuItem` from an ASP.net `NavigationMenu` by **`Value`**:

```
public static void RemoveMenuItemByValue(MenuItemCollection items, String value)
{
   MenuItem itemToRemove = null;

   //Breadth first, look in the collection
   foreach (MenuItem item in items)
   {
      if (item.Value == value)
      {
          itemToRemove = item;
          break;
      }
   }

   if (itemToRemove != null)
   {
      items.Remove(itemToRemove);
      return;
   }


   //Search children
   foreach (MenuItem item in items)
   {
       RemoveMenuItemByValue(item.ChildItems, value);
   }
}
```

and helper extension:

```
public static RemoveMenuItemByValue(this NavigationMenu menu, String value)
{
   RemoveMenuItemByValue(menu.Items, value);
}
```

and sample usage:

```
navigationMenu.RemoveMenuItemByValue("UnitTests");
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Answer (score 1):

I have my menu in the site master page.   I used the Page_Load() function to make the "Admin" menu item only visible to users with an Admin role.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Security;



<telerik:RadMenu ID="menu" runat="server" RenderMode="Auto"  >
    <Items>
       <telerik:RadMenuItem    Text="Admin"  Visible="true" />
    </Items>
 </telerik:RadMenu>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RadMenuItem item = this.menu.FindItemByText("Admin");
        if (null != item)
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
            {
                item.Visible = true;   
            }
            else
            {
                item.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but this is a telerik control, not a native asp.net one!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the parent menu in the page init event.

```
    Protected Sub navMenu_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles navMenu.Init
    'Remove the admin menu for the norms
    Dim cUser As Boolean = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin")

    'If user is not in the Admin role removes the 1st menu at index 0
    If cUser = False Then
        navMenu.Items.RemoveAt(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To find menu items in content page base on roles

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["AdminSuccess"] != null)
        {
           Menu mainMenu = (Menu)Page.Master.FindControl("NavigationMenu");

    //you must know the index of items to be removed first
    mainMenu.Items.RemoveAt(1);

    //or you try to hide menu and list items inside menu with css 
    // cssclass must be defined in style tag in .aspx page
    mainMenu.CssClass = ".hide";

        }   

}

<style type="text/css">
.hide
    {
        visibility: hidden;
     }
  </style>
```