# Is it possible to hide from some users some menu's elements while using ASP.NET menu control?

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

Let's say I have a menu that contains everything. But, I want some elements not to be visible to every user.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the menu items to a site map and use the roles attribute. You will need to enable Security Trimming in your Web.Config to do this.

You can find a nice tutorial at http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx

For more information, please check:  [Can I hide/show asp:Menu items based on role?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4939031/337294)