# How to disable a menu item on page load in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<Items>
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
</Items>
```

I have this menu How can I disable it during page load

```
page load
If (Userrole==Something)
{
hide menu item 2
}
```

How can I do that.

Comment: there's some code samples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939031/can-i-hide-show-aspmenu-items-based-on-role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //Going through first level items
 if (e.item.NavigateUrl == "")
    e.item.Enabled = false;

 //Going through submenu item
foreach (MenuItem item in e.Item.Items)
{
     if (item.NavigateUrl == "")
         item.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the runat and id tags to your menu items

```
<Items>
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" id="mnuDefault" runat="server"/>
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About" id="mnuAbout" runat="server"/>
</Items>
```

then in your codebehind you can program against them and set enabled = false

```
page load
If (Userrole==Something)
{
    mnuAbout.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most feasible solution will be security trimming. Simple and understandable. Read all about it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx)

Mark as answer if you found it useful. I benefited from it. Let me know if you have any doubts.