# Hide specific tabs in navigation menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation

I have the following navigation menu -

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/> 
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Test.aspx" Text="Profiles"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

In the code behind I can set visible to false -

```
((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu)Master.FindControl("NavigationMenu")).Visible = false;
```

However how can I access the specific MenuItems so that when Default.aspx loads, Test.aspx is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

```
MenuItem foo = menu.FindItem(""); // your particular item
menu.Items.Remove(foo);
```

also you can check this: [Can I hide/show asp:Menu items based on role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939031/can-i-hide-show-aspmenu-items-based-on-role)